# What are the max. overmold dimensions for USB-C plugs?

Tags: specifications, usb-c, dimensions

In contrast to earlier USB specs, the [USB-C specification](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019_0.pdf) doesn't seem to define a maximum width and height of the overmold part of the plug (according to figure 3.3, there is just a length defined).

1) What is the idea behind not even giving a recommendation for this?

2) If I am to design a device with several USB-C receptables, what spacing should I use (horizontally and vertically) to make sure, that 95% of common plugs will fit in next to each other?

*And yes, I did notice, that there are dimensions given for screwable USB-C plugs in [this sepc](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/usb_type-c_locking_connector_specification_rev_1_0_20160309_0.pdf), but those are obviously not relevant for normal plugs.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See figure 3-11 (page 57,58)

Page 58 has the width at 12.35 max and the thickness at 6.5 max

the locations of sections A-A and C-C are given by the drawings on page 57

figure 3-3 has this information too. (note. it also covers multiple pages)

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not understand this drawing before.

Comment: This helped me when designing a PCB with a USB-Plug on it. Now I will make sure the PCB is not over 12.35mm.

Answer (score 4):

I designed a housing with a recessed USBC socket based on the 12.35 x 6.5 dimensions shown in fig 3-11, plus what I thought was a generous allowance, to discover the hard way that some cable mouldings are bigger.

The biggest measured dimensions of a small selection of cables I bought were 13.0 x 7.4, however the connector was not always central in the moulding so allowance must be made for offsets too. Most plug manufacturers don't publish toleranced drawings so it's a matter of buying a selection and measuring them.

In the new housing I'm allowing 16.0 x 10.0 and hoping for the best...

Comment: Please focus on answering the question listed above.

Comment: Seems pretty on topic to me. The OP wants to know how far to space USB-C receptacles, and Peter not only gives the dimensions, as Jasen does, but gives additional important information that the spec does not seem to be adhered to and should probably not be used. I'm in the same boat and this is the answer that is more helpful to me.